Eddy currents in electroplated substances
Why is it, that whenever an application requires the use of magnetic breaking or another consequence of Eddy currents, solid blocks of metals are used?
I could be very wrong, but the eddy current equation does not have any terms that prescribe a certain necessary thickness, so shouldn't it be possible to generate them in electroplated substances?

That’s a great question, and I can see where you’re coming from! The theory behind eddy currents doesn’t say much about needing a certain thickness of metal, so it makes sense to wonder if something like an electroplated layer would work just as well. But when it comes down to practical applications—like magnetic braking—solid metal blocks are usually the best option, and here’s why.
One big reason is that eddy currents are essentially loops of current, and for them to have a strong effect, they need room to flow. A solid chunk of metal gives these currents a nice, continuous path, which makes them more powerful. Thin layers, on the other hand, just don’t have the same capacity for strong current loops.
Heat is another factor. Eddy currents generate heat, and thick blocks of metal can handle and spread that heat out way better than a thin layer. If you tried using a thin coating, it’d heat up really fast, which could wear it down over time, making it less effective. Solid blocks can take that heat without a problem.
And then there’s the strength aspect. In things like magnetic braking, you’re dealing with high forces, and solid blocks are sturdy enough to take that kind of stress. Thin layers? Not so much—they’d wear down a lot quicker, meaning more maintenance or replacements.
Finally, there’s the practical side. While, yes, thinner materials can technically produce eddy currents, making reliable, thin layers for heavy-duty applications isn’t as easy or affordable on a large scale. Solid metal blocks are just more practical and dependable.
So, even though the theory might suggest that a thin layer could work, real-world needs like durability, heat resistance, and strength mean that solid blocks are the go-to choice for applications relying on eddy currents.
